# ECRecover not recovering correct address, but works with ethers.js library

Tags: solidity, ethers.js, signature, ecrecover

Im trying to test some signature verification in Solidity.
I have generated the signature with nodejs using the ethers.js library.
The signature successfully verifies in nodejs.

I have tried to verify the same signature in solidity but it recovers a different signer address.

NodeJS Code

```
"use strict";
const ethers = require("ethers");

// remix account #0. Address: 0x5B38Da6a701c568545dCfcB03FcB875f56beddC4
var wallet = new ethers.Wallet("PK HERE");   

console.log("Wallet Address: " + wallet.address);    

async function SignData() {        

    var packedAddress = ethers.utils.solidityPack(["address"], [wallet.address]);
    var sig = await wallet.signMessage(packedAddress);

    console.log("Sig1 " + sig);

    console.log("Sig1 Valid? " + (ethers.utils.verifyMessage(packedAddress, sig) == wallet.address));

}

SignData();
```

Console output:

```
Sig1    0xbc223797d57c0cac4405c7751a54cae569c8a96c7a2296af28c18b45291a54f5774b1606277dfa1b19e83b24ab415e63b4dcd60be194f73c0ebe5cb3cd3e40e61c
Sig 1 Valid? true
```

Remix Code to verify the same signature

```
function testVerify(address signer, bytes memory signature_rsv) external pure returns(bool, address) {
    bytes32 hashedMessage = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(signer));

    (uint8 v, bytes32 r, bytes32 s) = splitSignature(signature_rsv);

    address recov_signer = ecrecover(hashedMessage, v, r, s);

    return (recov_signer == signer, recov_signer);
}

function splitSignature(bytes memory sig)
    internal
    pure
    returns (uint8 v, bytes32 r, bytes32 s)
{
    require(sig.length == 65, "Signature length is wrong !");

    assembly {
        // first 32 bytes, after the length prefix.
        r := mload(add(sig, 32))
        // second 32 bytes.
        s := mload(add(sig, 64))
        // final byte (first byte of the next 32 bytes).
        v := byte(0, mload(add(sig, 96)))
    }
    return (v, r, s);
}
```

Remix returns:

```
0: bool: false
1: address: 0x0E929401ba22b6b2035DdDc1A3D3F078E7779560
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, so `ethers.utils` is checking the two signatures successfully, whereas your mock up of the same functionality in `splitSignature` is not.

I believe it actually comes down to the way you are trying to create the assembly and might have declared `v` in the wrong way. Try

```
v := and(mload(add(sig, 65)), 255)
```

...also, having read the [docs](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/utils/cryptography/ECDSA.sol), is also super important to add the following line, due to the function of `web3` vs the EVM:

```
if (v < 27) v += 27;
```

Hope that helps.

**EDIT**

problem solved by @CathalMF

> I found the problem. The wallet.signMessage function of ethers.js
> automatically adds a "Ethereum Signed Message" prefix. So instead I
> used the wallet._signingKey().signDigest() function

Comment: No that didnt make any difference. Both your suggestion and the original post are valid ways to get the V value.

Comment: just to check, did you add `if (v < 27) v += 27;` ?

Comment: I found the problem. The wallet.signMessage function of ethers.js automatically adds a "Ethereum Signed Message" prefix. So instead I used the wallet._signingKey().signDigest() function

Answer (score 0):

I assume it's because node.js signMessage involves a default prefix: `"\x19Ethereum Signed Message:"`, which `ecrecover` in solidity excludes. In order to sign a message ecrecover can recognize, I suggest 2 solutions:

1. sign gthe message without `"\x19Ethereum Signed Message:"`.
2. while using `ecrecover`, include the aboved mentioned prefix in solidity code.